# Disable animations when opening applications

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher, docky, animations

I'm very new to ubuntu and currently have 13.04 running but have so far really enjoyed my experience.

A couple of days ago I installed 'Docky' as I prefer to have my shortcuts at the bottom of the screen and set the standard launcher to auto hide, as well as setting the sensitivity all the way down so it doesnt appear unless I really want it to.

My problem is that whenever I open a new application, or minimize an already opened application, a small icon animation appears on the left edge of the screen. I've posted an image below where you can see what im referring to, it's the small chromium icon on the left. I want to know the exact process in stopping these animations. I've installed COMPIZ and gone through all the settings but cant find which one would disable this animation when opening and minimizing applications.

Screenshot of what I'm referring to:

[image: Screenshot]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Unity does not have many customisation options, I'm afraid. For use with Docky I'd recommend to install a different desktop environment that does not use Compiz at all, or that can use Compiz without the Unity plugin active. Check out mate, xfce, lxde,...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about 13.04, but on 12.04 I had similar annoyances. These were the steps that I took:

1. Installed Compiz Settings Manager
2. Compiz Setting Manager -> Unity -> Experimental tab
3. ```
   Launch Animation: None
   Urgent Animation: None
   Hide Animation: Fade Only
   Dash Blur: No Blur
   ```
4. CSM -> Effects
5. Disabled everything except Windows Decoration
6. Installed a few Unity tweakers and made sure that settings there match ones in CSM.

In my case, MyUnity was still showing Hide Animation set to Fade and Slide, so I changed it to Fade Only there as well.